# Vector representation in PCA

Tags: vectors, machine-learning

Recently we studied [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).

As input, we have vectors:

$v_1,...,v_n \in R^d$ and $k$, where $k$ is the desirable dimension.

Then, we introduce matrix $A:$  $$A = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} v_iv_i^{T},$$ 
where $A$ is $d \times d$.

I have very naïve question: why is $A$ actually a matrix? Is $v_iv_i^{T}$ is a scalar, or I am wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$v_i=\left(\begin{array}{c}v_{i1} \\ \vdots \\ v_{id}\end{array} \right)$$
so
$v_i^T v_i =\sum_{j=1}^dv_{ij}^2$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^T v_i 
=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^dv_{ij}^2$ are scalars but
$$v_i v_i ^T=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}v_{i1}^2 & \cdots & v_{i1}v_{id}\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
v_{id}v_{i1}  & \cdots & v_{id}^2 \end{array} \right)$$
and 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n v_i v_i ^T=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} \sum_{i=1}^nv_{i1}^2 & \cdots & \sum_{i=1}^nv_{i1}v_{id}\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
\sum_{i=1}^n  v_{id}v_{i1}  & \cdots & \sum_{i=1}^n v_{id}^2 \end{array} \right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Why $v_i$ is actually a column vector. According to the problem $v_i$ is the vector of features. I thought it should be a row vector.

Comment: The convention I'm familiar with is that vectors are assumed to be columns.... in this case it must be.